# How to download DataURL as png on mobile using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mapbox

To preface, I am using mapbox to create a map then I use the `getCanvas` and `toDataURL` methods to get the image data.

Here is my code to download an image. So far, I am able to download the image properly on my desktop, but on mobile I download the image as file with no extension. I have to manually change the file to a `.png` then it works.

Is it possible at all to make sure that on mobile the file downloaded is a png?

I have tried using the `Image` class previously to no avail.

```js
        let dataURL = props.map.getCanvas().toDataURL();
        var download = document.createElement('a')
        download.download = 'map.png'
        download.href = dataURL
        download.target = '_blank'
        download.click();
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jespertheend/fwmu2apo/10/ are you using a specific browser?

Comment: I'm using the google chrome browser on my iPhone. Unfortunately when I run your jfiddle on my phone I am unable to download anything. If you want to give it a try, my site is https://danielchicchon.io/topo by clicking the `download map` button

Comment: Ah hmm yeah jsfiddle is not ideal for mobile. I have tried it in Chrome and the download button doesn't seem to work for me either. I think it might be a bug.

Comment: Ah yeah it seems to be a bug: https://crbug.com/1150258